# c#: How to automatically update a service?

Tags: c#, service, auto-update

This is probably a duplicate but I can't find recent posts and most sources recommend external tools.

We have a service that is installed via Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects. I assume for updating the service I need an additional tool that does the following:

1. Stop the service (or is it better to make the service itself check for updates and stop itself?)
2. Copy the new files to the install folder
3. Call `installutil.exe MyUpdatedService.exe` (or is this obsolete if the service is updated ?)
4. Start the service

We already have a tool for steps 1., 2. and 4. for regular applications. Do I need to implement a [ServiceController Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.7.2) to interact with the service or could any program start/stop the service?

Comment: Did you try using powershell or cmd like : net start SeviceName ?

Comment: No, is that how its supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an external c# application, you need `ServiceController`.
You could stop the service from within the service, but you cannot really start it afterwards.

You don't need to update service registration once it's registered, you only need to replace the service binaries.

1. Rename old service binaries while service is still running

   - Not sure if this is possible on all versions of Windows, also it has to be a rename.
2. Copy new version under the original name
3. Restart the service

   - This would unload the old version and load the new one.
   - The service interruption is the shortest possible.
4. Clean-up the old version

   - Once the old version is stopped, you'll be able to remove old binaries.